# Rendering vector objects from PDF file outputs incorrectly

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to render a PDF page to bmp image using PDFBox but all vector objects are rendered incorrectly. They are thinner than the image received from Adobe Illustrator.

For example, compare these images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIkhA.jpg

How do I correct this?

When I export the PDF page in Adobe Illustrator to bmp image, I use these options: bitmap color model, 600 dpi resolution, none anti-aliasing.

In Java:

```
...
BufferedImage img = pdPage.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 600);
...
File file = new File("img" + ".bmp");
ImageIO.write(img, "bmp", file);
```

I use PDFBox 1.8.9 and 2.0.0.

Input pdf: http://www.filedropper.com/examplevectortext

Adobe Illustrator output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKfjY.jpg

**

> I found a solution. First converted pdf to svg and changed all desired
>   settings there and then convert svg to image.

**

Comment: Could you please upload the PDF somewhere?

Comment: OK, I added link in post...

Comment: I rendered it with 2.0 at 600 dpi and compared it with Adobe Reader at 555% which looks like the same size, and it seems pretty identical to me. On the other hand, the Adobe Illustrator image of yours looks rather crappy, some glyphs are joined.

Comment: How did you do it? I used next sample [code in main()](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/rendering/CustomPageDrawer.java?view=markup)

Comment: renderer.renderImage(0) does not do 600dpi but 72dpi. use renderImageWithDpi. What I did (I'm lazy) was to use the PDFToImage command line option with 600dpi. But regardless of that, in your example it is the Adobe rendering that looks poor.

Comment: Yes, when compare with Adobe Reader all ok, but when compare with output bmp image from adobe illustrator it looks worse (text is thinner).

Comment: Obviously, the problem is with Adobe. I'm aware that most of the time PDFBox is to blame when rendering goes wrong, but the joined glyphs problem shows who is "guilty party" here. Maybe try PNG instead of BMP, and use anti aliasing. I see you added a new link, how come that this output is not different?